# Стиль для определенных тегов

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть такое простое меню, рубрика а сверху иконка из спрайта. Все работает, но стиль применяется ко всем тегам "i" на сайте.

Как сделать стиль только для тегов "i" в меню?

```css
i {
  background: url(/sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 27px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:6px;
  outline: none;
}



.kamaz {
 background-position: -3px -7px;;
}

.marsh {
  background-position: -223px -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary nav-menu">
   <ul id="menu" class="primary nav-menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="/">
         <i class="kamaz"></i>Камаз</a></li>
     <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="/">
         <i class="marsh"></i>Марш</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте более точный селектор

```css
.nav-menu i {
  background: url(/sprite.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 27px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:6px;
  outline: none;
}



.kamaz {
 background-position: -3px -7px;;
}

.marsh {
  background-position: -223px -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary nav-menu">
   <ul id="menu" class="primary nav-menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="/">
         <i class="kamaz"></i>Камаз</a></li>
     <li class="menu-item">
       <a href="/">
         <i class="marsh"></i>Марш</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Если использовать .nav-menu он почему-то подставляет для всех рубрик значок .kamaz. Использовал ul как точный селектор, вроде работает.

Comment: дело в том, что селектор `.kamaz` не может перебить селектор `.nav-menu i`. Селектор класса имеет больший вес, чем селектор тега. Поэтому при изменении `.nav-menu i` на `ul i` (два селектора тега), получилось вы ослабили вес этого селектора. Я бы рекомендовал усилить селектор иконки, а не ослаблять селектор пункта меню. Например: `.nav-menu i` и `.nav-menu .kamaz`. И почитайте про каскадность в CSS